# SUMIF across many sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheets document where several sheets have the same column layout. I'd like to sum column J if column G = "cat".

Essentially, this:

```
=SUMIF('A'!G3:G,"=cat", 'A'!J3:J) + SUMIF('B'!G3:G,"=cat", 'B'!J3:J) + SUMIF('C'!G3:G,"=cat", 'C'!J3:J)
```

But, with lots of sheets, that is cumbersome. How can I reduce that to something like this:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT({A,B,C}&"!G3:G"), "=cat", INDIRECT({A,B,C}&"!J3:J"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel) has a solution with `INDIRECT` array-formula, see it [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets).

Unfortunately `INDIRECT` [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20631477/5372400) iteration over an array in [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets)

Syntax `{A,B,C}&"!G3:G` is not possible.

## Workaround

The first step is to simplify the formula to:

`=SUM(FILTER({Sheet1!B:B;Sheet2!B:B},{Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A} = "Cat"))`

The hard part is to manually type all sheet names with ranges. I suggest to make a list of sheet names called `Sheets_List`:

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
```

And then use `join` to produce the proper formula text:

`="{'"&JOIN("'!B:B;'",Sheets_List)&"'!B:B}"`

The result is text `"{'Sheet1'!B:B;'Sheet2'!B:B}"`, use it to build the formula.

Comment: `=FILTER({Sheet1!B:B},{Sheet1!A:A} = "Cat")` works fine for any single sheet, but when I add a second sheet, I get an `#N/A` error `No matches are found in the filter evaluation`.