# How to loop over all sheets of a file in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google sheets for storing some simple text. In a column (F) I have all names of sheets and I'm using the following to count occurrences of a certain string "aaa" in column C in all sheets:

```
SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&F3:F11&"'!C3:C200"),"*aaa*"))
```

It returns only occurrences in the first sheet. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ARRAYFORMULA and INDIRECT to iterate rows and return as a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625539/using-arrayformula-and-indirect-to-iterate-rows-and-return-as-a-block)